# Set Word.Selection LTR from RTL

Tags: c#, office-interop, cultureinfo

I would like to set left-to-right alignment in a Word document using LtrPara() method.
Unfortunately it does nothing and the text goes from RTL. Any idea?

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document wordDoc = null;
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();  
wordDoc = wordApp.Documents.Add(ref defaultTemplate, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
//make a word selection object
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection selection = wordApp.Selection;
selection.LtrPara();
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are there any locale settings we should be aware of? For example, are you running in with culture settings where RTL is the norm?

Comment: Yes. my Word is default RTL

Answer (score 1):

This could be a defect in the Office Interop library. To test the theory, try setting your thread's culture to a LTR language before attempting the operation.

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-us");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass wordApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
```

If setting the thread culture works, it's possible that there's a less invasive way to set the culture for a document. For example, the Excel interop assembly offers the ability to override the number separators, as shown in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410936/specify-region-culture-for-microsoft-office-interop).

Comment: Thanks for quick reply! I have tried the code above but still- nothing happens.

Comment: Do you mean "nothing happens at all" or "no change"?

Comment: No change! The program does the same as before adding the code above.